# Import Excel to SQL Server 2005 using Sqlbulkupload

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to upload excel file using `SqlBulkCopy` into a SQL Server 2005 table. My excel file size is 43MB. When I am uploading this file it will display error message that

> The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request that
>   exceeds the request content length.

My web.config file setting is

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="12000" maxRequestLength="2097151" 
             useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" 
             minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`maxAllowedContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Optional uint attribute.
>
> Specifies the maximum length of
>   content in a request, in bytes.
>
> The default value is 30000000.

Not that this has *anything* to do with SQL Server or bulk copy...

Comment: I have tried maxAllowedContentLength but error : Unrecognized attribute 'maxAllowedContentLength'.  My IIS version is : 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: @Jayesh: if this answer solved your problem, **please** accept it as the "right" answer. This will encourage folks to continue to help you.